# If is true f(n) = Θ(g(n)) and if f(n) = o(h(n)) then g(n) = o(h(n))?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics

In asymptotic notation the transivity holds, however what happens when we have small o such as if f(n)= o(h(n)) does that means that also g(n)=o(h(n)) holds?

i take as granted that both of f(n)=o(h(n)) is true and f(n)= O(g(n)) (from THETA) then i need to show
g(n) < c h(n) given that i have f(n) <= d g(n) and f(n) < c h(n) how one would proceed from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ you know that, for some positive constants $c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\eta \in \mathbb{N}$, and for all $n \ge \eta$, it holds that $f(n) \ge c g(n)$, i.e., $g(n) \le \frac{1}{c} f(n)$.$^1$

Moreover, from $f(n) = o(h(n))$, you know that for *any* constant $c' > 0$ there is some $\eta'_{c'}$ such that $f(n) \le c' h(n)$ for any $n \ge \eta'_{c'}$.

Pick any constant $c'' > 0$ and let $\eta'' = \max\{\eta, \eta'_{c'}\}$ where $c' = c \cdot c'' > 0$.
From the previous inequalities we have that, for any $n \ge \eta''$:
$$
g(n) \le \frac{1}{c} f(n) \le \frac{1}{c} \cdot  c' h(n) =  c'' h(n),
$$
thus proving that $g(n) = o(h(n))$.

---

$^1$: In fact, the weaker condition $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ suffices.